# Confirm that a value is in a spreadsheet column using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

This function sends email reminders based on a few conditions. One of the things I need to check for is that the Visit ID (which is in column 11 in the "email log" sheet) exists in a separate sheet ("DATA", stored in the enrollmentData variable). How do I search this array and return the ID to match in the IF statement below?

```
function sendReminders() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email Log");
    var rows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
      var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
      var numRows = rows;   // Number of rows to process
      var now = new Date();

  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 22)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "m/d/yyyy")
  var reminderSent = "Reminder Sent";

  //get email body and subject
  var bodyTem = ss.getSheetByName("Email Templates").getRange('b8').getValues();
  var subject = ss.getSheetByName("Email Templates").getRange('d13').getValues();

  //get enrollments data to search for visit ID
  var enrollmentData = ss.getSheetByName("DATA").getRange('H:H').getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];




   //set conditions
    var sendReminder = row[18];
    var reminderDate = row[19];
    var reminderStatus = row[20];
    var visitID = row[11]
    //need condition to look for visit ID to not include already cancelled. Search enrollmentData for visitID and return as foundID for conditional below


    if (sendReminder == "Yes" && reminderStatus != reminderSent && reminderDate >= today && visitID == foundID) {


      //assemble email
      var studentEmail = row[13];
      var firstName = row[12];
      var instructor = row[0];
      var body1 = bodyTem.replace(/*name*/gi,firstName); 
      var body2 = body1.replace(/*instructorFull*/gi,instructor);



      MailApp.sendEmail(studentEmail, subject, body2);

      //need to write in that the reminder email was sent.
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 20).setValue(reminderSent);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 21).setValue(now);




    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Iterate through your enrollment array and test for equality with visitID: `var hasMatch = false; for(var j =0; j < someArray.length; ++j) { if ( someArray[j] == thingy ) { hasMatch = true; break; } }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to search the array

```
var enrollmentData = ss.getSheetByName("DATA").getRange('H:H').getValues();
```

The method `getValues` always returns a double array: in this case, it's of the form `[[1], [2], [3],..]` since each row has one element. I usually flatten this:

```
var enrollmentDataFlat = enrollmentData.map(function(row) {return row[0];});
```

Now `enrollmentDataFlat` is like `[1, 2, 3, ..]` so `indexOf` will work as usual:

```
if (enrollmentDataFlat.indexOf(visitID) != -1) {
    // it's there 
}
else {
    // it's not there
}
```